# How to return data from database normally when the input has been sanitized?

Tags: php, sql, curl, vue.js, html-encode

I have this web app and there are around 15 different files that deal with taking in user input.

Every time I take in user input, it sanitizes special characters using the filter_var() function as to not have any injection and whatnot.

However, I've been running into this problem where the data is being returned back to the front-end with those special characters encoded still, like this:

```
"'Sample & 'Code'"
```

becomes and goes to front-end like...

```
 &#x22;&#x27;Sample &#x26; &#x27;Code&#x27;&#x22;
```

or something like that; I think my point comes across.

My current strategy is go into every file in back-end and use

```
html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode([text], ENT_QUOTES))
```

to each output that could possibly have had user input.

Thus, my question is whether there is a more efficient manner of doing this. I'm using Vue on the frontend to curl the data received from the backend so I think it'd probably be the same amount of time if I did it on the front-end rather than the back-end. Any suggestions?

Maybe there is a current strategy out there that I should have kept in mind before encoding data into my database, but I'm hoping that someone can give answer that'll help me in future projects.

Answer (score 0):

For `php` you can use the [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function:

```
public function getSomeData() {
    ...
    return json_encode('Sample & 'Code');
}
```

my assumption here is that if you did a `var_dump('Sample & 'Code')`, it would print out `'Sample & 'Code'`

Comment: When I send it to the front-end, I'm sending it as you said, but the text is in an associative array e.g. 'result' -> "Sample &amp; 'Code'". The problem is the text isn't being decoded into "Sample & 'Code'", instead it looks like the associative array I just gave.

Comment: @DJSweetness I recreated your problem with `json_encode([ 'result'=> html_entity_decode("&#x22;&#x27;Sample &#x26; &#x27;Code&#x27;&#x22;")])` and I get `{"result":"\"'Sample & 'Code'\""}`.

Comment: I agree with the method of using json_encode, but you're using html_entity_decode to transform the data into viewable form, which is the answer to decoding the text, but my question is leaning more towards a design strategy or a simpler method rather than appending an html_entity_decode to all of my variables.

Comment: @DJSweetness I see your point. I guess you gatta look at the reason your data is in that format to begin with then. Or maybe use a `middleware` that will do that fore you every time you query data.